# mdadm.conf empty after upgrade to stretch attempt

Tags: debian, mdadm

Since I'm very confident, I updated today my jessie to stretch, following these instructions : https://angristan.fr/mettre-a-jour-debian-8-jessie-vers-debian-9-stretch/

Everything went well until the last line of the apt full-upgrade output :

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-4-amd64
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
```

I have an array on md0.
My mdadm.conf is

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan,     using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Mon, 27 Mar 2017 14:34:34     +0200 by mkconf
```

my fstab is

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=9b473d0e-84ab-4661-b03f-0ce5b56c215b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdc5 during installation
UUID=bc5f7676-5202-4202-903e-e50e6c4fcaf6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0

#/dev/md0
UUID=b1269cba-ec1b-4d68-b6a6-5f9830b5dfca   /mnt/raid5  ext4    defaults    0   2
```

I don't remember how I built the array, is there a way that I can regenerate this conf file (no I don't have a backup) ? I'm afraid if I reboot I will lose the array (I can copy files there is *only* 291 G of data).

I looked at this link https://serverfault.com/questions/867996/apt-get-install-linux-image-extra-getting-w-mdadm-etc-mdadm-mdadm-conf-defin but the answer is for someone having no array.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I guess I could get it with `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf force-generate /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` who modified the file, adding `ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=debian:0 UUID=0d56c6d6:e5b7507f:74e716c5:c920f08f`in it. Will copy all data anyway before I reboot, just in case...

Comment: No answer, I try the reboot :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf force-generate /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

did work : regenerated the configuration file, and all was ok after reboot. Finally it was simple.